# rake db:create error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I use ruby1.8.7, rails3.0.7 and mysql2(0.2.11). When I ran `rake db:create` for the new application, I got the following message. Is there somebody solve this problem before? Could you help me?

```
rake db:create --trace
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
WARNING: DSL method ApfSubsystem::Application#task called at /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize_tasks'
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:create
rake aborted!
can't convert Fixnum into String
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:14:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:14:in `mysql2_connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:229:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:229:in `new_connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:237:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:191:in `checkout'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:187:in `loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:187:in `checkout'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:186:in `checkout'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:94:in `connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:317:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:97:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in `connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:68:in `create_database'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:33
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
/usr/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:23
Tasks: TOP => db:create
```

Comment: please give your database.yml code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have an integer set as your username or password in database.yml - try wrapping it in quotes